# Parsing a date with short month without dot

Tags: java, locale, date-format

I have a String that represents a date in **French** locale :  09-oct-08 :

I need to **parse** that String so I came up with this SimpleDateFormat :

```
String format2 = "dd-MMM-yy";
```

But I have a problem with the month part, that seems to be expected with a ending dot :

```
df2.format(new Date());
```

gives me :

```
 28-oct.-09
```

What is now the best way for me to make SimpleDateFormat understand ("09-oct-08") ?

Full Code :

```
String format2 = "dd-MMM-yy"; 
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat(format2,Locale.FRENCH); 
date = df2.parse("09-oct-08");
```

This gives me : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09-oct-08"

And if I then try to log :

```
df2.format(new Date());
```

I get : 28-oct.-09

Comment: How did you manage to get the small `o` in `oct` without any extra effort on your part, BTW?

Comment: -) Just some offtopic comment. It`s interesting, how Enlish-spoken people forgot about such pretty and funny problems like locale-specific conversions, encoding grabage symbols, and so on.
Guys, just for fun - try to output this message to windows console - System.out.println("こんにちは！"). I promise - you will have a lot of funny troubles :)

Comment: Vinegar, I think it's simply the locale working here.   
The French locale displays and expects 'oct.' where the English locale displays and expects 'Oct'   
This is part of my problem as I use French locale but don't want to use the dot.

Comment: Sorry for the tag, Esko. Understood for the next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
    DateFormatSymbols dfsFr = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH);
    String[] oldMonths = dfsFr.getShortMonths();
    String[] newMonths = new String[oldMonths.length];
    for (int i = 0, len = oldMonths.length; i < len; ++ i) {
        String oldMonth = oldMonths[i];

        if (oldMonth.endsWith(".")) {
            newMonths[i] = oldMonth.substring(0, oldMonths[i].length() - 1);
        } else {
            newMonths[i] = oldMonth;
        }
    }
    dfsFr.setShortMonths(newMonths);
    DateFormat dfFr = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd-MMM-yy", dfsFr);

    // English date parser for creating some test data.
    DateFormat dfEn = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(dfFr.format(dfEn.parse("10-Oct-09")));
    System.out.println(dfFr.format(dfEn.parse("10-May-09")));
    System.out.println(dfFr.format(dfEn.parse("10-Feb-09")));
```

Edit: Looks like St. Shadow beat me to it.

Comment: Yeeee... Don`t work for french: for french locale we will have "févr." as febryary and when you truncate it - we will have "févr" - and this can not parse "fév" (as author mentored at his question). Need maula set all 12 month with date, that need to be parsed.

Comment: *If you will try to PARSE date, not to FORMAT

Comment: This seems to me a very elegant solution ! But I don't understand why you use dfEn ? Why not just use the dfFr you've constructed to directly parse the String ? And St.Shadow, why would not this work ?

Comment: Because I take a look at FRENCH shortMonthNames: they are [janv., févr., dontknow, avr., mai, juin, juil., août, sept., oct., nov., déc., ] - as you can see ferbryary here is "févr." and if you remove last dot - you will get "févr" and this is NOT "fév" and you can not parse string "fév" (as you mentored such name of febryary in your comments). If you will receive correct shormt month name, but only without dot - this solution will work good.

Comment: for truncuting month I use «less letters»
for (int i = 0; i < months.length; ++i) {
            months[i] = months[i].replaceFirst("\\.", "");
}
Do not check, is it more fast or not, but it shorter :))

Comment: St.Shadow, I think your solution and romaintaz's are more flexible (allows for abbreviations that are different from how the JDK does it), I just did this to prove the concept. As for parsing vs formatting, I figure as long as the formatted output is correct, the parsing behavior should be the inverse of it, and should work too.

Comment: Jalil, the purpose of dfEn is simply to parse and create test dates for testing dfFr (since I'm more familiar with the English behavior of SimpleDateFormat). I could have (and probably should have) just created the dates using GregorianCalendar, but didn't want to look that up. Hopefully this clear things up.

Comment: St.Shadow, I'm sorry I confirm that the only problem was the dot and that I'm indeed receiving "févr". 
So this solution seems the most elegant to me ! 
Thanks all for all your time and propositions !

Answer (score 7):

## java.time

Let’s see if the *java.time* framework can help.

### About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

Unlike the old classes, java.time offers the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class to represent a date-only value, with no time-of-day nor time zone.

### French Abbreviations

Take a look at what the formatters in java.time expect for abbreviated month names in *en Français*.

We can loop the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum to get a list of months. This enum offers the [`getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getValue--) method for generating a localized name of the month. This code demonstrates that the method produces the same output as the java.time formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MMM-yyyy" ).withLocale ( Locale.FRENCH );
for ( Month month : Month.values () ) {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of ( 2015 , month.getValue () , 1 );
    String output = formatter.format ( localDate );
    String displayName = month.getDisplayName ( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.FRENCH );
    System.out.println ( "output: " + output + " | displayName: " + displayName );// System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " → " + localDate + " → " + output );
}
```

```
output: 01-janv.-2015 | displayName: janv.
output: 01-févr.-2015 | displayName: févr.
output: 01-mars-2015 | displayName: mars
output: 01-avr.-2015 | displayName: avr.
output: 01-mai-2015 | displayName: mai
output: 01-juin-2015 | displayName: juin
output: 01-juil.-2015 | displayName: juil.
output: 01-août-2015 | displayName: août
output: 01-sept.-2015 | displayName: sept.
output: 01-oct.-2015 | displayName: oct.
output: 01-nov.-2015 | displayName: nov.
output: 01-déc.-2015 | displayName: déc.
```

We find a mix of 3 and 4 letter spellings. Longer names are abbreviated to four characters plus a period ([FULL STOP](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm)). Four months have names short enough to be used without abbreviation: `mars`, `mai`, `juin`, `août`.

So, as discussed in the other Answers, no simple solution.

#### Fix the Data Source

My first suggestion is to fix your data source. That source apparently fails to follow proper French rules for abbreviation. [Yale](http://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months.htm) agrees with Java 8’s understanding of French. By the way, if fixing your data source I strongly suggest using four-digit years as two lead to no end of confusion and ambiguity.

#### Fix the Input

Of course the source may be out of your control/influence. In that case, as with the other Answers, you may need to do a brute-force replace rather that attempt any cleverness. On the other hand, if the only problem with your input is simply missing the period (FULL STOP), then you could soft-code using the `Month` enum rather than hard-code the improper values.

I would make an initial parse attempt. Trap for the [`DateTimeParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html), before attempting a fix. If the exception is thrown, then fix the input.

To fix the input, try each month of the year by looping the possible set of enum instances. For each month, get its abbreviated name. Strip the period (FULL STOP) from that abbreviation, to match what we suspect is our improper incoming value. Test to see if that indeed is a match for the input. If not, go to next month.

When we do get a match, fix the input to be properly abbreviated for the Locale’s rules (French rules in our case). Then parse the fixed input. This would be our second parse attempt, as we made an initial attempt up top. If this second attempt fails, something is very wrong as noted in the `FIXME:` seen here. But normally this second parse attempt will succeed, and we can bail out of the `for` loop of the `Month` enum.

Finally, you could verify success by testing if the result is still the bogus flag value set initially ([`LocalDate.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN)).

```
String input = "09-oct-08"; // Last two digits are Year.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MMM-yy" ).withLocale ( Locale.FRENCH );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.MIN; // Some folks prefer a bogus default value as a success/failure flag rather than using a NULL.
try {
    localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // Look for any month name abbreviation improperly missing the period (FULL STOP).
    for ( Month month : Month.values () ) {
        String abbreviation = month.getDisplayName ( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.FRENCH );
        String abbreviationWithoutFullStop = abbreviation.replace ( "." , "" ); // Get short abbreviation, but drop any period (FULL STOP).
        String proper = "-" + abbreviation + "-";
        String improper = "-" + abbreviationWithoutFullStop + "-";
        if ( input.contains ( improper ) ) {
            String inputFixed = input.replace ( improper , proper );
            try {
                localDate = LocalDate.parse ( inputFixed , formatter );
            } catch ( DateTimeParseException e2 ) {
                // FIXME: Handle this error. We expected this second parse attempt to succeed.
            }
            break; // Bail-out of the loop as we got a hit, matching input with a particular improper value.
        }
    }
}
Boolean success =  ! ( localDate.equals ( LocalDate.MIN ) );
String formatted = formatter.format ( localDate );;
String outputImproper = formatted.replace ( "." , "" );  // Drop any period (FULL STOP).
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "success: " + success + ". input: " + input + " → localDate: " + localDate + " → formatted: " + formatted + " → outputImproper: " + outputImproper );
```

> success: true. input: 09-oct-08 → localDate: 2008-10-09 → formatted: 09-oct.-08 → outputImproper: 09-oct-08

Answer (score 3):

You can simply remove the ".":

```
df2.format(new Date()).replaceAll("\\.", ""));
```

---

Edit, regarding the *lemon* answer:

It seems to be a problem with the formatting when using the Locale French. Thus, I suggest that you simply use the `.` removal as I explained.

Indeed, the following code:

```
    String format2 = "dd-MMM-yy";
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format2, Locale.FRENCH);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format2, Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

displays the following output:

```
28-oct.-09
28-Oct-09
```

---

*Edit again*

Ok, I got your problem right now.

I don't really know how you can solve this problem without processing your String first. The idea is to replace the month in the original String by a comprehensive month:

```
        String[] givenMonths = { "jan", "fév", "mars", "avr.", "mai", "juin", "juil", "août", "sept", "oct", "nov", "déc" };
        String[] realMonths = { "janv.", "févr.", "mars", "avr.", "mai", "juin", "juil.", "août", "sept.", "oct.", "nov.", "déc." };
        String original = "09-oct-08";
        for (int i = 0; i < givenMonths.length; i++) {
            original = original.replaceAll(givenMonths[i], realMonths[i]);
        }
        String format2 = "dd-MMM-yy";
        DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat(format2, Locale.FRENCH);
        Date date = df2.parse(original);
        System.out.println("--> " + date);
```

I agree, this is awful, but I don't see any other solution if you use to `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes.

Another solution is to use a **real** date and time library instead of the original JDK ones, such as [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I though of this but I'm trying to do the reverse .... As my String does not have a dot and SimpleDateFormat seems to need it to parse the String ...
Maybe I could add the dot to my input String but this don't appears to me to very "clean" coding ...

Comment: I agree that it is not a good solution, but it seems to be a "bug" (?) in the SimpleDateFormat class with the French locale...

Comment: Please note that I'm not trying to **FORMAT** a Date as a String, but to **PARSE** an incoming String as a Date. 

So there is no dot in my incoming String, but SimpleDateFormat *needs* this dot to "understand" the month ...

That is my problem.

Comment: sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format2, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(sdf.parse("09-oct-08"));
Will be ok.

Comment: St. Shadow, as I said to Lemon, I cannot use the ENGLISH Locale because I'm receiving french date.   

While it's OK for October (Octobre in French), It would be problematic for February for exemple (I will receive 'fév' and not 'Feb').

Comment: Ok, I got your problem now. I give you an awful solution to solve your problem. A better idea is to move to joda library!

Comment: If this is only one place, where we need new month names - no sence in third party libs. Just use givenMonths for DateFormatSymbols solve the problems.

Comment: Yes I think these are the only 2 solutions. 
I'm not adding a new library for the single code ligne, but thank you for pointing it to me, I'll take a look. 
So for now, I think I'm gonna use the givenMonths->realMonths solution. Ugly but working.

Answer (score 2):

```
String format2 = "dd-MMM-yy";
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format2);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Outputs `28-Oct-09`

I don't see any dots sir. Have you tried re-checking your prints? Maybe you accidentally placed a `.` beside your `MMM`?

---

You're getting `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09-oct-08"` since `"09-oct-08"` does not match the formatting of `Locale.FRENCH` either use the default locale(US I think) or add a `.` beside your `oct`

Comment: And what about locale? Do you set French locale Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE)?

Comment: I just run your example, and I get the output `28-oct.-09`. Are you sure that you used the French locale? (I use Java 6)

Comment: As I said, this is because I'm working on French Locale ... Try with this : 

    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat(format2,Locale.FRENCH);

Comment: Romaintaz, my code is :  
  
String format2 = "dd-MMM-yy";  
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat(format2,Locale.FRENCH);  
date = df2.parse("09-oct-08");  
This gives me :   
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09-oct-08"  
And if I then try to log :   
    df2.format(new Date());  
I get :  28-oct.-09

Comment: Formatting in comments is awfull, I'm updating my main question.

Comment: Lemon, I cannot use the US Locale because I'm receiving french date.   
While it's OK for October (Octobre in French), It would be problematic for February for exemple (I will receive 'fév' and not 'Feb').

Comment: Okay, why not just adapt to the french locale version then? parse oct. instead of oct, that would eliminate the error.

Comment: Yes this is the only solution I can think of, adding the dot before the second "-". 

But first, it is not very pretty. 

And second, I fear the French locale does not have a dot for May for exemple, as the month is not shorten. I'm testing it right now.

Comment: I confirm : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10-mai.-09" :-(
"10-mai-09" works OK. 
Yeah I know FRENCH locale sucks here :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, then try «brute force» :)

```
DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH);
String[] months = new String[13]
<fill with correct month names or just replace these month, that are not fully correct>
dfs.setMonths(months);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", dfs);
Date nweDate = sdf.parse("09-fév-08");
```

Comment: :-( This will not work with "02-mai-10" for 2 reasons :   
  
First, "Mai" is "May" in english.   
Second, "Mai" does not have the dot in FRENCH locale, as the month name in NOT shorten.

Comment: "March", "June", "July" and "August" also are not "standardized" (they are "mars", "juin", "juil." and "août").

Comment: you can fill months array with any month names with/withot dots and so on. You can even fill with fake names: for example: month[0] = "dontknow". And it will parse sdf.parse("09-dontknow-08").

Comment: I like the DateFormatSymbols solution ! I did not know this class, which direct use is not recommanded by the API :-(
I can see that your months array is sized 13. Why not 12 ?

Comment: Also I think I should rather use setShortMonths() method.

Comment: 13 - because origing dfs.getShortMonth() return array of size 13 - last is "" - look like for unrecognized month, but I don't take a look at it, so can not say exactly.

Comment: Your right, for short month names you should use setShortMonths() method. setMonth() for full name (I think, you understand me :) )

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
//from w  w  w  .j  av  a 2  s . com
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy",
        Locale.FRANCE).format(new Date());
    System.out.println(timeStamp);

  }
}
```

link : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Type_How_to/Legacy_Date_Format/Show_a_date_in_french_format.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).